# Can't find variable: _ when using jasmine to test AngularJS service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, lodash

I am testing an AngularJS service that uses the Lodash library. When I run the tests through karma-jasmine I get an error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: _
```

Is there a way to configure karma/jasmine to use Lodash?

Comment: Have you included the lodash library in your karma.config.js? Sounds like it isin't included in the files property. http://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/files.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you won't have a HTML file in your tests to load the script for you, you'll need to include the library in your karma config file in the `files` property. You can read more about it here: http://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/files.html

It will look something like this

In karma.conf.js

```
...
files: [
  'path/to/lodash.js'
]
...
```

Hope that helps!